# Question tags: "Hardly seems... Doesn't it?" vs "hardly seems...does it?"

Tags: double-negation, question-tags

---

Is it correct to use a negative question tag in this sentence:

"It hardly seems fair, doesn't it?"

Bit confusing, because if I wrote "it doesn't seem fair, ..." The correct tag would be a positive "does it?"

But "it hardly" is essentially "it does hardly..."

It appears that the negative tag is grammatically correct, but I think it still sounds wrong to the ear.

Answer (score 2):

[*Hardly*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hardly) means to almost no degree; **almost (does) not**; though it is not *purely negative*, it's use still follows the double negation rule.

> It *hardly* seems fair = It **almost does not** seem fair

Therefore there shouldn't be a negative tag with it.

The same holds true for *barely, scarcely,* and *rarely*. They all carry the **force of a negative**.

> It hardly seems fair, does it?
>   It's barely worth the effort, is it?
>   It's rarely simple, is it?
>   We could scarcely complain, could we?

Though some people might use a negative tag after hardly, barely, scarcely and rarely, it would be unacceptable in standard English.

Answer (score 1):

*It hardly* is equivalent to *it doesn't* in your example. So the tag question should be in the positive.

*Hardly* is a negative. So, although you could say *it does hardly* is equivalent to *it hardly*, *it does hardly* is also equivalent to *it does not*.

Another example is "it is hardly worth the effort" is a slightly less negative version of "it is not worth the effort".